# To get the value after space in String Java

Tags: java, string, extract

I have String of values .

Like as

```
String line= "cpu  74608   2520   24433   1117073   6176   4054";
```

i just want to extract these Values and store them in different variables.

Is there any way that i can get the Numeric values after every space ??

Comment: the split method can help you there. just add a regex for an indefinite nr of spaces as delimiter, and you'll get an array filled with the values you're looking for as result

Comment: Note that using @Stultuske's code you will get an *array of Strings*. You will have to convert / parse the data into appropriate *type* if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the options you have is to use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. It accepts regex, so you can skip any number of spaces:

```
String[] values = line.split("\\s*");
```

Then you'll have to convert these `String`s to the values you need:

```
int firstNum = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
// anything like this
```

If you're OK with storing it as an array/list, but not as different variables, maybe you'll want to extract all numbers this way (Java 8):

```
int[] numbers = Stream.of(values)
        .filter(str -> str.matches("-?\\d+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray();
```

Maybe, the easier way would be using [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
String firstStr = scanner.next();
int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
// and so on...
```

Comment: Side note on wording: nobody **has** to use split() to solve this problem. There are other options; so there is no need to artificially reduce the option space to "split".

Comment: @Jägermeister OK, I'll fix the wording.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String input = "123 456 123 578";
    String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
    for (String s : numbers) {
        System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(s));
    }
```

output:

```
123
456
123
578
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String thisString="Hello world";

String[] parts = theString.split(" ");
String first = parts[0];//"hello"
String second = parts[1];//"World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You  could start off by splitting the data into a array:

```
String [] lineSplit = line.split("\\s+");
```

And then begine parsing the data into individual variables:

```
int foo = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
    if(lineSplit[i].matches("\\d+") {
        foo = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[i]);
    }else {
        //Do something else...
    }
}
```

And repeat the above for different data types and add variable etc. to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Use `String.split()` and `Integer.parseInt()` as show below:

```
    String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String num: split) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // not a number
        }
    }
```